# I would like to install blender on my raspberry pi4

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, linux, software-installation, opengles

I am trying to install blender 2.79 from the software packages on my new raspberry pi4.  It won’t do it.  How do I install and run blender?

Comment: "from the software packages" - which software packages is that? how are you trying to install blender exactly? what errors do you see when you try?

Comment: It ended up loading.  Not sure what I did but I’m happy.

Answer (score 1):

Please prescribe which os you are running, If it is the official raspberry pi os you can easily download blender using the add/remove software or typing the following command in the terminal:

```
    sudo apt install blender
```

I have been able to run blender 2.79 on raspberry pi os and the performance is also good.